# materialize not work well with select2

Tags: jquery-select2, materialize

I found the document  in  materialize UI framework with select2 .

when I did not add   $("select").selet2();  everything is ok . the page like this:
[image: normal page]

when I add .select2() function, the page not work well :

the line under select disappeared .
[image]

I push my code into github , and here is the repository:

https://github.com/SeasonXin/material-select2-issue.git

hope somebody's support, very thanks ;

Answer (score 1):

Adding the class 'browser-default' to the select element will fix that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I found this
https://github.com/nikitasnv/materialize-select2

In the case of labels, enter these styles

```
style = "position: absolute; top: -14px; font-size: 0.8rem"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Spelling Error**.

Use

```
select2()
    ^
```

instead of

```
selet2()
```